# Running grep on conf.xml widget definitions

Tags: tooltwist

I'm looking for pages defined by the ToolTwist Designer that use a specific widget. I've tried using grep to search for the widget name but nothing is found, even though I've checked it is in the file.

This is the command I'm using to check a specific page definition:

```
grep myproject.TestWidget widgets/test_pages/testPage/scratch_me/conf.xml
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The widget definition files are stored as UTF-16 (but my change in the future). Before running grep, convert the file like this:

```
iconv -f UTF-16  -t ISO-8859-15 widgets/test_pages/testPage/scratch_me/conf.xml \
         | grep myproject.TestWidget
```